# How to set format on yml files for storage units `number_to_human_size`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

Is the code below the correct format for `number_to_human_size`? I placed them under five, [en:, es:, de:, it:, fr:] .yml files.

```
storage_units:
  format: "%n %u"
  units:
    byte:
      one: "Byte"
      other: "Bytes"
    kb: "KB"
    mb: "MB"
    gb: "GB"
    tb: "TB"
```

I have following reference

```
<%= number_to_human_size(@game.downloadsize, :precision => 2, :locale=>I18n.locale) %>
```

I am getting the error message:

> can not load translations from C:/Documents and Settings/rajg/antixdiscoveraws/config/locales/de.yml, expected it to return a hash, but does not

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to indent the format:

```
storage_units:
  format: "%n %u"
  units:
    byte:
      one: "Byte"
      other: "Bytes"
    kb: "KB"
    mb: "MB"
    gb: "GB"
    tb: "TB"
```

Comment: tried it above, I am getting above error message, could you have a look please?

Comment: Can you update the code of the yml file? In general remove all unnessary spaces and dont use tab. Always use 2 blanks/spaces to format the yml file. The error msg is a indicator for a wrong file format. And maybe ensure that windows doesnt save the file in a strange encoding.

Comment: what reference do i need to provide to use those format! I have following reference `<%= number_to_human_size(@game.downloadsize, :precision => 2, :locale=>I18n.locale) %>`

Comment: well, I have solved the problem by doing this `:locale=>'en'` so regardless of anything: it shows the correct size on all the languages. also I commented out those format from yml files. Anyways I am accepting this for your valiant effort. Thanks